# Read elements of an array from keyboard Assembler

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, long-integer, tasm

I am new to Assembler Language, working on TASM, need to sort the numbers in ascending order. The code is simple, but I have to read from keyboard the number of elements of the array and then insert them also from keyboard. The problem is that everything you type is seen in ASCII code, and I don't have any idea about conversion. How can I do the reading ?

Thank you in advance!

**Sorting 5 numbers**

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.DATA 
NUM DW 42H,34H,26H,17H,09H 
LEN EQU 05H

.CODE 
START: 
MOV AX,@DATA 
MOV DS,AX 
MOV BX,LEN-1  ;Initialize BX as the counter for loop UP 
MOV CX,BX     ;Initialize CX as the counter for loop UP1

UP1: MOV BX,CX 
LEA SI,NUM    ;SI points to the first number in NUM

UP: MOV AX,[SI] 
MOV DX,[SI+2] 
CMP AX,DX 
JB DOWN         ;no swapping if [SI] less than [SI+2] 
MOV [SI],DX 
MOV [SI+2],AX   ;swap the numbers pointed by SI and SI+2 
                ;if [SI] is greater than [SI+2]

DOWN:
INC SI 
INC SI       ;increment SI to point to next dataword(number) 
DEC BX 
JNZ UP 

DEC CX 
JNZ UP1 

MOV AH,4CH 
INT 21H 
END START 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you read in the string, and convert it - char by char.
the algorith could be described like this

```
for each digit in String
   value *= 10
   value += value(digit)
```

ill give you a sample:

```
string "4132"

"4" is a digit, so value = 10*value (=   0) + digit (=   4)
"1" is a digit, so value = 10*value (=  40) + digit (=  41)
"3" is a digit, so value = 10*value (= 410) + digit (= 413)
"2" is a digit, so value = 10*value (=4130) + digit (=4132)
no more digits, we're done
```